# Lightning Design System Table Footer

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I'm using the Lightning Design System to style an `apex:dataTable` in Visualforce, and so far, all is well. It looks beautiful, the size is right, the headers show as expected. I'm embedding it in a page layout, and it looks great in Aloha too!

Normally, when I am building a data table to summarize some data, I define a quick CSS class named `.bold` which just sets the font-weight, and in the dataTable I set `footerclass="bold"`. It gets the job done and the totals row looks just fine. This works as expected in an LDS table, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Is there a component in the LDS `table` class for summary footer rows? I feel like there should be something for accessibility, and I'd rather not depend on my own classes when there's stuff in LDS...

**How should I style a summary (footer) row in a Lightning Design System Datatable?**